# Can't use Anaconda properly due to package installation error

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, python-import, spyder

I'm using Python 3.8 with pyCharm generally but for some Machine Learning tutorial I wanted to use Anaconda Spyder 4.1.2. So when I write in default windows cmd

```
    C:\Users\Ege>python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

when I write in anaconda prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ege>python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

This is the version of my base(root) environment. I searched and found Anaconda supports 3.8 for environments but not for base yet. Therefore I cannot upgrade it to 3.8. Now the problem comes:

When I try to use numpy in Spyder it says there is no module imported called numpy. I went and check my anaconda base environment and yes there is no numpy package. I opened the conda prompt and I wrote

```
pip3 install numpy
```

It says:

`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.18.1)`

But goddamit you don't allow me to use python38.

Some of you can say okay go make a new environment with python38 and use the packages. However I want to install the packages to base environment. Any ideas ?

Comment: I recommend using `conda install numpy`. If you do want to use pip, you can use `python -m pip install numpy`. pip3 is not belonging to your anaconda python version - it installs numpy to the wrong place.

Comment: Okay thats perfect thank you for that. Do you know a one-click installer from sypder for needed packages ? Because otherwise I need to open and write the package name everytime when I try to use a new package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of usin pip one should use conda install. the names are not always equal to each other which means sometimes `pip install thisPackage` is not equal to `conda install thisPackage` therefore one should search before installing that package to their environment.